# Error while upgrading sensu puppet module: Invalid parameter prefetch on sensu_rabbitmq_config

Tags: rabbitmq, puppet, upgrade, sensu

I'm trying to upgrade the sensu-puppet module and im getting an error when i run puppet now: the error is:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Invalid parameter prefetch on Sensurabbitmqconfig[<(hostname
>   is here, removed for this post on ask puppet)>] at
>   /etc/puppet/environments/staging/modules/sensu/manifests/rabbitmq/config.pp:123
>   Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog Error: Could not retrieve
>   catalog; skipping run

I have no idea what's going wrong or how to fix it. I looked in the pathway at the rabbitmq config and found this:

> prefetch => $sensu::rabbitmq_prefetch

But I'm not sure what the issue is. Anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get the puppet module and what way?
Did you use puppet module install or a git pull?
Make sure sure that the parameter you want to use is in 
`modules/sensu/lib/puppet/provider/sensu_rabbitmq_config/json.rb`
and also 
`modules/sensu/lib/puppet/type/sensu_rabbitmq_config.rb`

Comment: I used puppet module install, and then i copied all of the files from the directory it was installed to into the directory where my previous version of the sensu puppet module and its dependencies were installed. that's all I did to get to this point.

Comment: when you installed this sensu puppet module from [here] (https://forge.puppet.com/sensu/sensu/1.1.0), this is really really really outdated and you cannot use this prefetch with this. A better approach to this is to get current puppet module from [github] 9https://github.com/sensu/sensu-puppet) which includes all the new function and variables and what not

Comment: Sorry, I did install it from the github, not the forge, so i don't think this might be the issue